# Numero de columnas en SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

Buenas estoy empezando con SQLite y queria hacer una consulta para saber el numero de columnas de una tabla, o sus nombres.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta consulta devuelve los nombres de los campos de tu tabla pruébalo.

SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('TU_TABLA')

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Si que me funciona, mil gracias.